# How to stop redirecting external http Links to https on the WP-page

Tags: wordpress, http, ssl, https

After I moved my website from Http to Https, now when I click on a http link on the page, directs me to https link.

I changed all 'http's to 'https' using a plugin in wordpress. Now Website works perfectly, but every single external links in the page directes me automatically to https.

I tried WP-Elementor and added new http links, but still directs me to https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin which you use for redirect url from http to https is redirect all the link without checking the domain. you need to use plugin which is check the domain. and your domain links only redirect from http to https. As of me good plugin to redirect from http to https is Really Simple SSL.